# Admob banner not shown

Tags: android, admob

I'm facing a strange problem by adding adMob banner to my app. 
It's first time i do this with android studio, so i've followed tutorial (the only different thing is the edit of build.gradle file).

I've add banner to layout as always:

```
<RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_cut"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/banner" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and initialized banner into my activity:

```
 AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.banner);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
 mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Now when i launch my app, banner space is empty, and i obtain some warning like

```
W/Ads﹕ Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 328x479 dp.
```

but log told me that banner is loaded correctly:

```
I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 40000 milliseconds from now.
I/Ads﹕ Ad finished loading.
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: please show your complete layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will see, successfully:

```
I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 40000 milliseconds from now.
I/Ads﹕ Ad finished loading.
```

AdMob may or may not complain about "having enough room" but it will not show up if there is padding in the parent view. You need to wrap the views you want to have padding in either another layout or add padding to that particular view directly.

Please remove the padding from the parent layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_cut"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/banner" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't really need padding, it was added automatically by ide

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still struggling I've found a working example on http://www.ahotbrew.com/android-studio-admob-banner-and-interstitial-tutorial/

Just click on download code.